# what is the meaning and purpose of modeling a data?

Tags: mixed-model, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

**Background**:

I collected a whole years access logs of my website, counted visit frequency for every user, and the numbers of user at each unique frequency, I got a distribution: $n_w \tilde\ D_w(f_w ; \theta_{w})$, I also counted numbers of user who accessed a certain page at each unique frequency, I got another distribution: $n_p \tilde\ D_p(f_p; \theta_{p})$, along the way I got the 3rd distribution $n_r \tilde\ D_r(r_{p,w}; \theta_{r})$, where $r_{p,w} = f_p/f_w$, means a user's frequency of visiting that certain page, say $p_c$, divides the frequency s/he visited by website, I was expecting a Gaussian-like distribution, while I got $D_r$, which looked like pic.2. $D_p$ and $D_w$ all looked like pic.1(plz ignore the numbers in the pic, I only plotted part of my data), which resembled a Poisson distribution.(Here, $D_*$ means some distribution, $n_*$ represents number of users, $f_*$ means some kind of frequency.)

[image: user num distribution on visit frequency]

[image: user num distribution on f_p/f_w]

Look at pic.2, I think it's accumulated with curves in pic.1, each that curve represents a certain $f_w$.

**What I Want**

I was expecting $D_r$ to be a Gaussian-like distribution, So I could assume that users with a too low or too high $r_{p,w}$ accessed $p_c$ by accident, or with an abnormal reason, and all the rest really needed the infos on that page, **so I could tell how many users really interested in that page**, this is what I really want to know.

**My Questions**

1. If $D_r$ is a Gaussian-like distribution, can I use it to tell users who are really interested in $p_c$?
2. Now that the distribution is not what I expected, should I involve more information, e.g. take the time interval between a user's visits into account, come up with new variables, util I find a variable that has the distribution I expect? and the variable should include $f_p$, $f_w$, and other information, so the big amount of users whose $f_w$ and $f_p$ are both 1 can be separated into different groups by this **ideal** variable, if it exists.
3. Should I model my data, what can I get from modeling my data, the distribution parameters?
4. The data I have is more like a population than a sample, so is it still necessary to find some way to **evaluate** it's parameters rather than calculate them directly?